# Trying to round the results of a sql query to 2 decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

In the following query, I'm trying to return the data with 2 decimal places (.00) for the SUM line:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(COALESCE(release_date, requested_date)))
  + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(COALESCE(release_date, requested_date))), 2) AS yrmnth,
  salesrep,
  customer_name,
  SUM(price_per_ea * COALESCE(open_release_qty, open_order_qty)) AS ext_price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use convert for take control over the format

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(COALESCE(release_date, requested_date))) 
    + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
 MONTH(COALESCE(release_date, requested_date))),2) as yrmnth
,salesrep
,customer_name
,  Convert(decimal(12,2), 
     SUM(price_per_ea * COALESCE(open_release_qty, open_order_qty)))  as ext_price
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in your select:

```
round(SUM(price_per_ea * COALESCE(open_release_qty, open_order_qty)),2)
```